How do you broadcast and live from a system with OBS Studio without having the application?
I have a system to make live shows and transmissions with OBS Studio, where basically with the application, you create your live show on my system, using the transmission key and the server, you place it in OBS Studio and the live show works well. But, they have asked me that the user does not have to enter OBS Studio to create the live stream. That is, the direct can be created from the same system.
Comment that I use PUSHR as a content distributor. This is the function that creates the Stream.
This is the function that creates the stream:
$options = name, portada....
$httpClient = new Client();

        // disabled SSL
        $httpClientConfig = [
            'verify' => false,
        ];

        $createStreamingRequest = $httpClient->request(
            'POST',
            self::PUSHR_API_ENDPOINT . '/stream',
            [
                'headers' => [
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                    'APIKEY' => $apikey_pushr,
                ],
                'form_params' => array_merge([
                    'action' => 'create',
                    'zone'   => $zone_pushr,
                    'name'   => $options['name'],
                ], $options['settings']),
                'http_errors' => false, te
            ] + $httpClientConfig
        );

        return json_decode($createStreamingRequest->getBody(), true);

If it is possible to create streams with OBS Studio as a user without having the application?

It's technically possible to stream just using the web browser, as you can stream from Discord web or MS Teams, but that requires deep browser integration and isn't going to be as full-featured or performant as OBS without a lot of work.

@Sammitch  Thanks, Is there no way to get the streams to connect to OBS to create Streams from the system itself?

I have no idea what you're asking.

Sorry I'm not sure what this is about either. You apparently want to use some software without actually using it...that's about as much as I can figure out. You can [edit] your question and try to clarify it, if you need more help. Don't assume, as general PHP programmers, that we'll know anything about your specific scenario...you may need to explain what OBS studio does and what you're trying to do, in more detail. If there's a stackoverflow tag for it, add that and you may get more people with relevant specialist knowledge looking at your post. Thanks.
